# the issues on two lines of C++ codes

Tags: c++, stl

For the following two lines of C++ code

```
map<string, vector<size_t> >::iterator beg = mapper.begin();
vector<size_t>& indics = (*beg).second;
```

How to understand what do they want to achieve, and in specific, what do the `&` and `*` in the second line of code mean?

Comment: Wow, all comments, some of which contained valid advice, none of which were remotely offensive, were removed.  Why have a comment section at all?  No one was fighting, no insults were thrown around.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `map<string, vector<size_t> >::iterator beg = mapper.begin();`

We have a `map` that maps from `string` to `vector<size_t>`. We get an `iterator` to the first element in the map, that would be the one with the lesser key value, according to `std::less<string>`.

> `vector<size_t>& indics = (*beg).second;`

or what is the same

> `vector<size_t>& indics = beg->second;`

We get the second value in the *key-value pair*, that is we get the `vector<size_t>` for the first element in the map. We keep a non-const reference to it, so we can modify its values.

Comment: Just one more thing (it is not trivial for a beginner): `map` contain `pair`s (not keys and values separately), where the `first` is the key (and `const`) and the `second` is the value. Map is a `set` of `pair`s with comparison only for the `first` value.

Answer (score 2):

```
map<string, vector<size_t> >::iterator beg = mapper.begin();
```

Is declaring an iterator to the beginning of the map of string to vector.

```
vector<size_t>& indics = (*beg).second;
```

Is declaring a reference (&) to the vector which is the second member of the pair after dereferencing the iterator (*beg) probably for the purpose of changing some of the indices.

Iterators are a big part of STL containers. If you aren't familiar with them I'd recommend picking up a good book or googling for C++ STL tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

`beg` is a iterator for a `map`, which you can dereference (syntactically, just like a pointer) to get a `pair` with fields `first` and `second` corresponding to the key (a `string`) and value (a `vector` of `size_t`'s).

So `*beg` refers to the pair, and `(*beg).second` gives you a reference to the vector, which then gets stored in a local variable `indics`.  (It's cleaner to write this `beg->second` of course.)

The `&` in the type declaration for indics means that the variable is a reference.  The vector is not being copied, indics simply becomes a local "name" for the vector stored in the map.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you learn C first - which is a very simple language, and then start learning C++ when you have the C basics.

Your question really has nothing to do with the map class.

```
// this is a number.
int foo = 5;

// this is a pointer to foo. You can use this to refer to any thing of type "int"
int* pFoo = &foo;

// now you are getting the number back from the pointer. This creates a copy 
// of foo. If you change bar, foo will not change.
int bar = *pFoo;

// this is a reference to foo. E.g. another way of talking about foo. If you change 
// foo2, foo will also change.
int& foo2 = *pFoo;
```

Comment: -1 for the suggestion to learn C as a primer to learning C++.  +1 for the explanation of pointers and ref's.  Net zero.

Comment: I agree with John about learning C first, but still +1 because I believe your main point is that the OP needs to go back and learn the basics. IMO this is the only helpful response here (the others are correct, I just don't think they help someone who doesn't understand pointers and references.

Comment: Learning C is not really a good start for C++. They're like two different languages, and C brings over some quite nasty habits.

Comment: Wow. Mark me as very surprised. It not like I'm saying that all good C practice is good C++ practice. But C is a nice clean language that would teach someone about pointer semantics for sure and get you using a lot of the same api calls that you use in C++. Do people think it is bad in general for programmers to learn multiple languages because they will learn "bad habits"?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify more on the "(*beg).second;"

I guess this is the confusing part, since beg is treated as a pointer but it was not declared as such. More over, it might not be clear where the "second" came from, since it is not declared in the iterator class.

What we need to realize is that beg is just a normal object of type iterator for which the * operator has been overridden.  So, when you do "*beg", this is calling a method, not trying to use a pointer.

Now, the * operator implementation in the iterator class returns the current element, just like a pointer, and that's why the * operator is used, to make it more obvious, though it might be confusing at first.

For example, look at the declaration of an iterator in the .h file:

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator, class T, __DFL_TMPL_PARAM(Reference, T& ),
    __DFL_TYPE_PARAM(Distance, ptrdiff_t)> 
# endif
class reverse_bidirectional_iterator {
    typedef reverse_bidirectional_iterator<BidirectionalIterator, T, Reference__,
                                           Distance> self;
    friend inline bool operator==(const self& x, const self& y);
protected:
    BidirectionalIterator current;
public:
    typedef bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef T                          value_type;
    typedef Distance                   difference_type;
# if defined (__STL_MSVC50_COMPATIBILITY)
    typedef Pointer                    pointer;
# else
    typedef T*                         pointer;
# endif
    typedef Reference                  reference;

    reverse_bidirectional_iterator() {}
    explicit reverse_bidirectional_iterator(const BidirectionalIterator& x)
      : current(x) {}
    BidirectionalIterator base() const { return current; }
    Reference operator*() const {
        BidirectionalIterator tmp = current;
        return *--tmp;
    }
```

Note the declaration of the * operator at the end.

So the * is returning a map element. A map element is always of type " struct pair ", which has a "second" element declared. Again, just check the pair's .h file:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct pair {
  typedef T1 first_type;
  typedef T2 second_type;
  T1 first;
  T2 second;
...
```

So, a call to ( *beg ).second is executing the * operator of the iterator for a map, A map is a series of "pairs", and a pair is a struct that has first and second elements. In this case we are getting the indexed element "second", which, in this case, is a vector.

In the other hand the following & is a regular reference, so you get a reference to the vector, not a copy, so you can change the value in the map.

I hope that made sense.

-Alejandro